# Onclick Redirect Not Firing

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onclick

I'm trying to redirect a user to another page after clicking on a form submit button.

I'm trying to fire a few events which fill in certain parts of the form automatically then submit the form & finally redirect the user to another page.

Everything works expect the redirect. I have tried a few things but havent gotten the redirect to work after the form submits.

I also don't want to user to be redirected before the form has been successfully submitted.

Here is my code:

```
<form id="usp_form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
  <input class="usp_input" type="text" name="user-submitted-title" id="user-submitted-title" value="" />
  <input class="usp_input" type="text" name="user-submitted-url" id="user-submitted-url" value="">
  <input class="usp_input" type="text" name="user-submitted-tags" id="user-submitted-tags" value="">
  <input class="usp_input" type="text" name="user-submitted-category" id="user-submitted-category" value="">
  <textarea class="usp_textarea" name="user-submitted-content" id="user-submitted-content" rows="5"></textarea>
  <input class="hidden" type="hidden" name="user-submitted-name" value="<?php echo $current_user->user_login; ?>">

  <input onClick="copyText();copyText2();copyText3();handleClick();" class="usp_input" type="submit" name="user-submitted-post" id="user-submitted-post" value="Submit Post">
</form>



<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function copyText3() {
var output1 = document.getElementById("edit1").innerHTML;
var output2 = document.getElementById("edit2").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("user-submitted-title").value = output1 + ', ' + output2;
}
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function copyText2() {
var output1 = document.getElementById("edit1").innerHTML;
var output2 = document.getElementById("edit2").innerHTML;
var output3 = document.getElementById("template").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("user-submitted-tags").value = output1 + ', ' + output2 + ', ' + output3;
}
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function copyText() {
var output = document.getElementById("templatebody").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("user-submitted-content").value = output;
}
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function handleClick() {
window.location.href='http://website.com/';
}
</script>
```

Comment: where handleClick() is called..?

Comment: so quick to edit code..

Comment: are you sure your functions are getting called..?

Comment: lol - You guys are quick this thing got like 8 views in 2 seconds - I needed to edit a few things - but its all there now. :)

Comment: `onclick` happens **before** `onsubmit`, and since your `form` submits to self frame (no `target` -> defaults to `_self`), either your redir or the form will overwrite the current frame. If you need to ASYNC, use AJAX to submit the form.

Comment: Go AJAX way if you need this

Comment: I noticed some php in there. Have you considered using `header`? Javascript can be disabled but php can't :)

Answer (score 0):

The submit button will launch a request, but you are also defining a redirecting request on the button press, so one will override the other (I'm not sure which one, it may depend on the browser).

You may want to fire an Ajax request instead of the standard submit, and do the redirection only when you get the response from the Ajax request so you are sure no information was lost.

Answer (score 0):

You should not code like is but register your functions on the event, outside de HTML (it's always better to separate your HTML, JS and CSS).

You can understand about events bubling here : http://javascript.info/tutorial/bubbling-and-capturing

If you just want to see your code working and don't validate your form, just add "return false ;" at the end of your onclick attribute.

Edit : Oups sorry, you want submit your form, then redirect. You can do this with ajax requests (see http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) : you submit your form in ajax, then you redirect.

But IMO, It's a serverside behaviour : you probably have a dynamic language (Python, PHP, ASP... ?) which process your form submission. It's here you have to redirect after the process.

Comment: I get what your saying in regards to adding the redirect in the serverside php file. I'll take  alook into what I can add into the php file after the form submits on the serverside.